# Make thumbnail from jpg, jpeg or png

Tags: python, django, image, thumbnails

I have the following method to create a thumbnail, but I would like it also to generate it in case the file type is **png**, as it currently throws an error for them (`cannot write mode RGBA as JPEG`):

```
from io import BytesIO
from django.core.files import File
from PIL import Image


def make_thumbnail(image, size=(600, 600)):
    im = Image.open(image)
    im.convert('RGB')
    im.thumbnail(size)
    thumb_io = BytesIO()
    im.save(thumb_io, 'JPEG', quality=85)
    thumbnail = File(thumb_io, name=image.name)
    return thumbnail
```

How can I effectively accept png, jpg and jpeg to generate the thumbnail?

Comment: If an error is thrown, you should give it to us.

Comment: Just added, sorry about that